# bat script to compile py2exe

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file, py2exe

hello i know this is kind of a dumb question but i need help writing a bat script to make a python file run it then delete it all of this is simple but i cant seem to get it to work my code:

```
@echo off
set /p %file% = type the file you want to make to exe:  
echo from distutils.core import setup >> setup.py
echo import py2exe>> setup.py
echo setup(console=['%file%'])>> setup.py
Python-Portable.exe setup.py py2exe
pause
del "setup.py"
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /p "file=type the file you want to make to exe: "
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- [`SET` command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)